# Undefined name and getter not found

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List items = [];
  bool isLoading = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    this.fetchItems();
  }

  fetchItems() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    var url =
        'https://api.torn.com/torn/?selections=items&key=7PnSA9HkVB5B6eAK';
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var things = json.decode(response.body)['items'];
      setState(() {
        items = things;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        items = [];
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hej Tomek!'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: getBody(),
    );
  }
}

Widget getBody() {
  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length, // Here is problem
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return getCard();
      });
}

Widget getCard() {
  return Card(
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(),
        title: Text(''),
        subtitle: Text(''),
        trailing: Text(''),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

items seems to be undefined, and my android Studio told me that 'Getter not found: 'items'.'
I was trying to pass items from Json to ListView, but can tell why my items is not defined.
Im trying to figure it out for last 2 hours and i was searching for answer but no one has similiar problem to mine im thinking that its really simple oversight from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined `getBody()` outside the scope of your `HomePage` class. Either put it inside `HomePage` or simply modify your `getBody` to match this:

```dart
Widget getBody(List items) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: items.length, // Here is problem
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return getCard();
    },
  );
}
```

Your `build()` should then be:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Hej Tomek!'),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: getBody(items),
  );
}
```